# Windows 8.1 - Check for updates not loading

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

Windows 8.1 will not load updater. I'm getting the following screen with the spinner...

[image: Cropped screenshot]

I've tried resetting windows update components with the microsoft tool [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058) and get the following results every other time I run it:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image]

Comment: Did you try rebooting after fixing?

Comment: Yep a few times but same result.

Comment: Try running DISM to repair your component store then run SFC fix your system files.  You have corrupt system files.

Comment: @Ramhound Done and done but still the same unfortunately.